# Reading a text file and calling each array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, txt

I am reading a `.txt` file using `f.read`. But I also want to assign it as a list and call each array within this list . I present the current and expected output.

```
f = open("Test.txt", "r")
print("f read =",f.read()) 
print("f 0 =",f[0])
```

The current output is

```
f read = [array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         4.02753575e+002,  3.79606698e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.01629825e+002,  2.73930748e+002,  2.73930748e+002,
         1.44270041e-014, -1.19840421e-014,  2.48466223e+002,
         4.07808390e-014,  2.23084563e+002,  2.23084563e+002,
         1.95133833e+002, -1.90524280e-014,  1.13675881e+002,
         1.60355972e-023,  8.87020057e+001,  6.51230922e+001,
         8.87020057e+001,  1.00000000e-100])
 array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.96370317e+002,  3.82498020e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.77200451e+002,  3.22917850e+002,  3.49391875e+002,
         3.24649000e+002,  3.06639099e+002,  3.06639099e+002,
         3.06639099e+002,  2.74439993e+002,  3.06639099e+002,
         2.42357202e+002,  2.42357202e+002,  2.26139235e+002,
         3.06639099e+002,  2.22347429e+002,  1.64667856e+002,
        -1.26698275e-013,  1.69645075e+002,  1.07059051e+002,
         1.95176276e+002,  1.00000000e-100])                 ]


Traceback (most recent call last):

  in <module>
    print("f 0 =",f[0])

TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output is

```
f read = [array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         4.02753575e+002,  3.79606698e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.01629825e+002,  2.73930748e+002,  2.73930748e+002,
         1.44270041e-014, -1.19840421e-014,  2.48466223e+002,
         4.07808390e-014,  2.23084563e+002,  2.23084563e+002,
         1.95133833e+002, -1.90524280e-014,  1.13675881e+002,
         1.60355972e-023,  8.87020057e+001,  6.51230922e+001,
         8.87020057e+001,  1.00000000e-100])
 array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.96370317e+002,  3.82498020e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.77200451e+002,  3.22917850e+002,  3.49391875e+002,
         3.24649000e+002,  3.06639099e+002,  3.06639099e+002,
         3.06639099e+002,  2.74439993e+002,  3.06639099e+002,
         2.42357202e+002,  2.42357202e+002,  2.26139235e+002,
         3.06639099e+002,  2.22347429e+002,  1.64667856e+002,
        -1.26698275e-013,  1.69645075e+002,  1.07059051e+002,
         1.95176276e+002,  1.00000000e-100])                 ]

f 0 = array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         4.02753575e+002,  3.79606698e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.01629825e+002,  2.73930748e+002,  2.73930748e+002,
         1.44270041e-014, -1.19840421e-014,  2.48466223e+002,
         4.07808390e-014,  2.23084563e+002,  2.23084563e+002,
         1.95133833e+002, -1.90524280e-014,  1.13675881e+002,
         1.60355972e-023,  8.87020057e+001,  6.51230922e+001,
         8.87020057e+001,  1.00000000e-100])
```

Comment: when you call `f.read()` you should assign what this method returns to a variable. something like `data = f.read()`

Comment: have you tried using `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read()`

Comment: With ```f.readlines()```, I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Test.txt` file contains:

```
[array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         4.02753575e+002,  3.79606698e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.01629825e+002,  2.73930748e+002,  2.73930748e+002,
         1.44270041e-014, -1.19840421e-014,  2.48466223e+002,
         4.07808390e-014,  2.23084563e+002,  2.23084563e+002,
         1.95133833e+002, -1.90524280e-014,  1.13675881e+002,
         1.60355972e-023,  8.87020057e+001,  6.51230922e+001,
         8.87020057e+001,  1.00000000e-100])
 array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.96370317e+002,  3.82498020e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
         3.77200451e+002,  3.22917850e+002,  3.49391875e+002,
         3.24649000e+002,  3.06639099e+002,  3.06639099e+002,
         3.06639099e+002,  2.74439993e+002,  3.06639099e+002,
         2.42357202e+002,  2.42357202e+002,  2.26139235e+002,
         3.06639099e+002,  2.22347429e+002,  1.64667856e+002,
        -1.26698275e-013,  1.69645075e+002,  1.07059051e+002,
         1.95176276e+002,  1.00000000e-100])                 ]
```

then, assuming the arrays in question are NumPy arrays, you can do:

```py
import numpy as np

# read in the whole file
with open("Test.txt", "r") as f:
    inputdata = f.read()

# parse the data with eval
data = eval(
    inputdata
    .strip()  # remove trailing whitespace
    .replace("\n", "")  # replace new lines with empty strings
    .replace(")", "),"),  # stick a comma between the arrays
    {"array": np.array}  # make sure it knows to parse array as a NumPy array
)

print(data[0])

array([ 4.24805745e+002,  0.00000000e+000,  0.00000000e+000,
        4.02753575e+002,  3.79606698e+002,  0.00000000e+000,
        3.01629825e+002,  2.73930748e+002,  2.73930748e+002,
        1.44270041e-014, -1.19840421e-014,  2.48466223e+002,
        4.07808390e-014,  2.23084563e+002,  2.23084563e+002,
        1.95133833e+002, -1.90524280e-014,  1.13675881e+002,
        1.60355972e-023,  8.87020057e+001,  6.51230922e+001,
        8.87020057e+001,  1.00000000e-100])
```

Note that the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function can execute arbitrary code, so only use it if you trust the source of your input file.